# Is there a difference in creating viewmodel as default argument vs. inside composable body?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

Is there a difference between creating a viewmodel as the default value of a composable parameter vs. creating it inside the body of the composable?
I don't think there should be any but just wanted to confirm my intuition.

Is there a difference between:

Scenario 1:

```
@Composable
fun Foo(fooViewModel = viewModel()) {
}
```

vs.

Scenario 2:

```
@Composable
fun Foo() {
 val fooViewModel = viewModel()
}
```

Comment: The first one allows for swapping the implementation in unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Using first one will break your preview + for both options you gave, you will have to create viewmodel instances when writing tests. Instead, you should either create your viewmodels in your navGraph's composable scope where your compsable placed or wrap your composable with somewhat 'Route' composable that is responsible for creating viewmodel then you should only pass necessary states and function references to your actual screen.

Here is an example:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.profileScreen(
    navigateToPairDetail: (String) -> Unit,
    navigateAndPopUp: (String) -> Unit
) {
    composable(ScreenHolder.ProfileScreen.route) {
        val viewModel: ProfileViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
        val userState by viewModel.userState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
        val searchState by viewModel.searchState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
        val searchedList by viewModel.searchedPairList.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
        val uiText = viewModel.eventChannel
        val uiEvent = viewModel.uiEvent

        ProfileScreen(
            user = userState ?: User(),
            onEvent = viewModel::onEvent,
            state = state,
            searchedList = searchedList,
            navigate = navigateToPairDetail,
            uiText = uiText,
            uiEvent = uiEvent,
            getAnalyzeCount = viewModel::countOfAnalyze,
            navigateAndPopUp = navigateAndPopUp,
            searhState = searchState
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the first one is going to break the preview?

Comment: @BenjyTec I didn't technically dig into it but my bet would be on compose compiler's state processing logic. Since composables'  recomposition strategy depends on whether the parameters supplied are changed or not, there should be interpretable parameters by compiler but a viewModel function wouldn't be the one I guess

Comment: Its being predefined, does not mean it can be interpretable.

Comment: Here is the official documentation about the incompatibility with ViewModels and Previews and also a workaround: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews#preview-viewmodel

Comment: @SevbanBayır that's helpful, thanks! As I understand navcontroller is only good for root component for a route. But what about a component that exists inside of a route that does not have a route in navigation?

Comment: @J.Cool you can create that components viewmodel instance at the same place, you can then pass that specific component's state (whatever it needs) to its parent - that is, the screen in this case -

Answer (score -2):

Scenario 2: you will receive an error:

> 'val' on function parameter is not allowed

Comment: The `val` declaration in scenario 2 is inside the function body, not within the function signature.